# Nested Scroll. Auto scroll one after another has reached its end point

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a nested scroll view situation such as follow-

mainView->ScrollView1->ScrollView3(has many child ScrollView vertical)

[image]

***I want that when that when the user scrolls down then,first the scrollView1 will scroll dragging the displayed *childScrollView3* along with it.(scrollView2's user interaction as well as scroll should be disabled)***

2)*And after it has reached its end the *childScrollView3* will scroll with the same velocity that scrollView1 was scrolling ?*

Same should happen when user scrolls downward i.e *childScrollView3* will first come to its end & then the scrollView1 shall scroll to top.

**UPDATE**

***Mark*** - I searched on goole for parallax but that was not helpful as I have a paging scroll view with multiple vertical child scrolls.

Comment: I think you are wanted to scroll view like Parallax please refer this link might be you get some idea about. : http://www.michaelbabiy.com/parallax-scroll-view-in-swift/

Comment: No Because I have other reuirment that the  last scroll view is actually a horizontal scroll view having many vertical scroll views embedded in it.

Comment: your concept is related to parallex scrolling .... search on google once you get easy answer bro

Comment: very complicated bro..

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik But every complicacy has a solution

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik But there might be some way

Comment: @KamalaDash -- simple Idea , but works, create one tableview, on your indexpath.row (0) add the normal data. ok , indexpath.row (1) add one scrollview thats all bro , it will work, got it

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik No didn't get you. Can you please be a bit elaborate

Comment: sure bro ,if you take multiple tableview it is complicated , give 3 minutes I update my answer

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Are you there bro..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105133/discussion-between-anbu-karthik-and-kamala-dash).

Comment: @NitinGohel Can you please check my updated question?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik heyy bro I am waiting for your suggestions.....?

Answer (score 0):

override the
`func scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` in `UIScrollViewDelegate`
method to watch for the fine grain scrolling of the UIScrollViews.

You can use the `contentOffset` variable of the scrollView to find when you should start scrolling the next one.  You'll have to do some math to determine how much the scrollView the user is touching was offset in-between calls of this method to determine how much to scroll the next scrollView by to keep the "animation" the same across both.

Comment: Good suggestion but....eg - my scrollView1 has to scroll for y=150 & then my horizontal scroll i.e horizontalScrollView3 has to be dragged upto 150 points up alongwith the scrollView1 & then the childScrollView3 will scroll without breaking i.e the scroll should be continuous without any chop. Can you please suggest some demo codes....that would be really very helpful.